# @QueryParam boolean gets false even though 'true' was passed

Tags: java, rest, http, javax.ws.rs, query-string

Invoking a REST with a boolean parameter receives the value `false` even though passing `true` on the client side.

Client:

```
$http.post("http://localhost/getServers/?light=true")
```

Server:

```
@Path("/getServers")
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getServers(
  @Context HttpServletRequest request,
  @DefaultValue("true") @QueryParam("light") boolean light)
{
  // light is false even though true was passed
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the slash (`/`) before the question mark (`?`) was the problem.

After removing the slash on the client side, everything worked fine.

This worked:

```
$http.post("http://localhost/getServers?light=true")
```

BUT, from reading on the web, a slash preceding a question mark is a legitimate syntax :(

Comment: It is legitimate in a general HTTP request but not for the contract you wrote, i.e. `@Path("/getServers")` is not the same as `@Path("/getServers/")`.